# Passing an immutable list to ImmutableList.copyOf()?

Tags: java, guava, immutability, defensive-copy

I have the following code:

```
private static final ImmutableMultimap<String, String> namesToAddress;

public static List<String> getAddresses(String name){
  return ImmutableList.copyOf(namesToAddress.get(name));
}
```

My question is wheter the defensive copyOf() here is necessary, as the get() returns an immutable list anyway?

Note I am using ImmutableMultiimap from Google Guava.

Thanks.

Comment: `ImmutableMultimap#get`  returns an `ImmutableCollection`. There's no need to copy it. If you need a `List` however...

Comment: In the Google Guava docs( http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html) it states mmutableMultimap#get returns an ImmutableList<V>...

Comment: Also, `ImmutableList.copyOf` will not actually copy an `ImmutableList` anyway.

Comment: @user1974753 You're looking at `ImmutableListMultimap`, but your code has `ImmutableMultimap`. In any case, they're both immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple things (mostly covered in the comments, but as an answer):

- If you use `ImmutableListMultimap` as the type for `namesToAddresses`, `get()` will return an `ImmutableList`; no need to call `copyOf` or cast or anything
- Even if you don't do that, `ImmutableMultimap.get()` will return an `ImmutableCollection`; `ImmutableCollection`s have an `asList()` method to view (or copy if necessary) the collection as an `ImmutableList`
- Calling `ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableCollection)` will end up calling `asList()` on the collection anyway